# iOS 9 Spotlight Search. Whats the proper amount of data to index?

Tags: ios9, spotlight

I have an app which is basically a collection of multipage news articles.  This articles contain for example 2000-3000 words sometimes.  Im right now starting the implementation of iOS9 Spotlight Search.

For now I'm including the ***entire*** text of the article as the contentDescription of my index'd item in the CSSearchableItemAttributeSet.

**Is this the correct way to index my articles?**

It seems like it will really add up in the iOS database to index these very large articles one after another, but what do I know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use NSUserActivity public indexing and CoreSpotlight to index a subset of content that is most relevant for the user, such as the most popular items or the ones in the geographic location. You should not blindly add thousands of items using NSUserActivity and CoreSpotlight. Instead, focus on adding items that users actually interact with or have identified as meaningful in some way to people.